# include_lowest giving unexpected results in pandas.cut

Tags: python, pandas

So the following code (mydata is a `pandas.Series` with floats in X.XX format with min being above 1.195, in case that matters):

```
bin_range =[ 1.195,  2.655,  4.115,  5.575,  7.035,  8.495,  9.955, 11.415,
       12.875]
out, bins  = pd.cut(mydata, bins=bin_range, include_lowest=True, right=True, retbins=True)
print(out.value_counts(sort=False))
print(bins)
```

Gives me this output:

```
(1.1940000000000002, 2.655]    19
(2.655, 4.115]                 12
(4.115, 5.575]                 17
(5.575, 7.035]                 15
(7.035, 8.495]                  5
(8.495, 9.955]                  8
(9.955, 11.415]                 2
(11.415, 12.875]                2
dtype: int64
[ 1.195  2.655  4.115  5.575  7.035  8.495  9.955 11.415 12.875]
```

And I'm not sure where "1.1940000000000002" comes from (floating-point problems?) and why it actually is not included despite `include_lowest=True`.

I am trying to print a frequency table of a histogram plot I generated, thus ideally the bins should be something like `[), [),...,[]` to cover the whole range, which seems impossible with `pandas.cut`, unless I'm missing something.

**Edit:** It seems that because of `IntervalIndex`, all `include_lowest` does is decreasing the lowest bound by `precision`. So instead of actually including 1.195 it turns it to 1.194 (though it fails at that too apparently)

Comment: i dont have a direct solution to your issue, but i have something that might just help. You could add an extra starting interval 0 - 1.195, if it does not create any issues elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a "hack" for the time being, and I'm putting it here in case it's useful for someone:

```
out  = pd.cut(mydata, bins=phist, right=True, include_lowest=True)
z = out.value_counts(sort=False)
new = z.index.rename_categories({z.index[0]: pd.Interval(phist[0].round(3), phist[1].round(3), closed='both')})
z = z.reindex(new, fill_value=z[0])
print(z)
```

It basically replaces the first Interval, but due to `include_lowest=True` being false, the values are still correct regardless of our manual filling with `fill_value=z[0]`.

Giving us:

```
[1.195, 2.655]      19
(2.655, 4.115]      12
(4.115, 5.575]      17
(5.575, 7.035]      15
(7.035, 8.495]       5
(8.495, 9.955]       8
(9.955, 11.415]      2
(11.415, 12.875]     2
```

It still doesn't replicate how NumPy handles intervals (we have no `include_highest` for some reason so we can't guarantee correctness), but stil making more sense as it doesn't drop data off our bins.